# How to access the Flash controls through Watin

Tags: flash, watin

I would like to know how do we test Flash elements using Watin. I have file uploader in flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not supported by WatiN. And, the reason why I think so, is because there are classes modeled for each HTML element in WatiN. And Flash, happens to be a non HTML entity, an ActiveX plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would apply in your situation but you can control flash using javascript. From Watin it is possible to execute/evaluate javascript statements/commands.

Here is an example:
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/

I imagine it should be possible, for example, to start playing the flash using this statement:

```
Browser.Eval("PlayFlashMovie()");
```

Though you would be limited to flash interaction to what is provided through javascript, it is better than nothing.